# Kaspersky blocks PostgreSQL 8.4.1 installation

Tags: postgresql, kaspersky

I was just installing PostgreSQL 4.1 with Drupal and other tools. While the Setup was installing phpWiki.exe, Kaspersky blocked the Setup and quarantined two files:

phpWiki.exe, and

StackBuilder.exe

The actual message that Kaspersky report says:

Legal software that can be used by criminals for damaging your computer or personal data. PDM.Worm.P2P.generic.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: The question is why it is showing virus like activity while the installation files are extracted?

Comment: Because anti-virus is a completely unreliable crock that does more harm than good in 2009?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaspersky has real-time protection. As files are being written and executed they are scanned by the software. From what I see, those 2 programs seem legitimate. Kaspersky's [heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_algorithm) seem to think they are conducting suspicious behavior, but it's likely a false positive.

Comment: Agreed. I think it is the heuristics that is giving false positive.